# Trying to change the background of my QR code to transparent using PIL and qrcode libraries on python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I seem to encounter a mental block. I have a python script which is a basic app to generate QR codes from a CSV file and compile them on a PDF.

What I am trying to do is to change the background of the QR code to a transparent one, instead it always appear as a black background. I tried using fpdf library, changing the image to RGBA, etc.

Please help me to achieve this!

Here is the part of my code that generates the QR code:

```
def generate_qr_code_with_text(data, text_row1, text_row2, text_row3, output_path, qr_size_pixels=227):
    try:
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data(data)
        qr.make(fit=True)

        img = qr.make_image(fill_color=(255,255,255), back_color=None)
        img = img.resize((qr_size_pixels, qr_size_pixels))

        final_img = Image.new('RGBA', (img.width, img.height + 90), color=(255, 255, 255, 0))
        final_img.paste(img, (0, 0))

        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(final_img)
        font = ImageFont.load_default()

        text_row1_position = (final_img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] + 10)
        draw.text(text_row1_position, f"Row 1: {text_row1}", fill="black", font=font, anchor="mm")

        text_row2_position = (final_img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] + 30)
        draw.text(text_row2_position, f"Row 2: {text_row2}", fill="black", font=font, anchor="mm")

        text_row3_position = (final_img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] + 50)
        draw.text(text_row3_position, f"Row 3: {text_row3}", fill="black", font=font, anchor="mm")

        final_img.save(output_path)
        return True

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

Comment: Please read about [mcve] - emphasis on ***minimal***. Do you really want to wait until someone comes along who knows about PDFs and PIL and `tkinter` and QR codes? Or can you simplify your question down to just PIL?

Comment: Is there a way to have `qr.make_image` generate a RGBA format image from the start?

Comment: Thanks, I just simplified my code to just the QR code part, which only uses PIL and QR codes.

I added everything if it helps to envision what I want to do

Comment: Now the code is neither runnable (it doesn't include necessary `import` statements), nor complete (it doesn't call any functions or have any sample data). Nor does it show what outputs you get, nor what you actually want.

Comment: Okay, I just solved it, it is an easy solve... just set the back_color='transparent' and it worked.. 
Thank you for your help and feedback on posting questions. This is my first post

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
        img = qr.make_image(fill_color=(255, 255, 255), back_color="black")
```

To

```
        img = qr.make_image(fill_color=(255, 255, 255), back_color="transparent")
```